# MYSQL and Symfony errno 150 while creating ManyToMany Association

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have a problem while creating the database tables automatically with the symfony 2 console. I get an errno 150 in MySQL when i want to alter the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE roles (
    role_id SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    role_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    role_role VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_649AC6AFE9D6F8FE (role_role),
    PRIMARY KEY (role_id)
)  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE persons (
    person_id SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
)  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE persons_roles (
    person_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    role_id INT NOT NULL,
    INDEX IDX_EA478DBA217BBB47 (person_id),
    INDEX IDX_EA478DBAD60322AC (role_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id , role_id)
)  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This are the alter commands.

```
ALTER TABLE persons_roles 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EA478DBA217BBB47 
FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES persons (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE persons_roles 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EA478DBAD60322AC 
FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Could someone point me to my error?

Comment: What's the correct error message?

Answer (score 0):

**For 1st Alter**

You don't have column `id` in `persons` table the column is `person_id` so the correct `ALTER` is as

```
ALTER TABLE persons_roles 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EA478DBA217BBB47 
FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES persons (person_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

**For 2nd Alter**

**Issue**

1. You don't have column `id` in `roles` table the column is `role_id`
2. The column type is also not same `roles.role_id` is not same as `persons_roles.role_id`

**Solution**

First change the column type and then refer to correct column.

```
ALTER TABLE roles MODIFY role_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE persons_roles 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EA478DBAD60322AC 
FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles (role_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem. Symfony got in it's automatic schema update the columns wrong.